# Android android dependencies annotations.jar in ADT 18

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, adt, noclassdeffounderror

I'm using **Eclipse indigo**, With **jdk 1.6**.. And I've upadated my Android plugin from **ADT 14 to ADT 18**, When i create new project or when ever i clean projects **Android dependencies with annotations.jar** is appearing on my project how do i remove it, this is causing lots problem while adding external jars(Such as **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** exception) ..?

I read this link http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17 he explains about ADT 17. if i rename lib folder to libs, Referenced Libraries will remains in Project

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am having the same issue right now ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this problem, annotations.jar is a required jar for building android projects.. If u have any TargetApi and SuppressLint annotation in your project then this jar will help u to  ignore the specified warnings for the annotated element.

Answer (score 0):

adt18 can automatically link jars, you just need to create folder named "libs", and then copy your jars into that folder, no more operation should you do. Just this easy.

But I think it's a mess change! Hope to help you.

Comment: Ya i did that, How do i remove annotation.jar

Comment: Why? I think you just need not remove the annotation.jar, that's required.